# Subquery based on max number of related rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm using Oracle 11g R2.

I want to return a single value from a table which has multiple child rows.
The subquery must return the value based on the max number of values of a second unrelated column.

The following code provides data in form of CTEs... and a failed attempt to create the statement.
I know I have to differentiate somehow the values so that it returns the one that has the max number of child.

Check on the snippet "Expected result".

```html
WITH GRPS(GRP, SUBGRP)
AS
(
    SELECT 'AAA', 'SUB_A1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AAA', 'SUB_A2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AAA', 'SUB_A2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AAA', 'SUB_A2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AAA', 'SUB_A3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'BBB', 'SUB_B5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'BBB', 'SUB_B6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'BBB', 'SUB_B6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'BBB', 'SUB_B7' FROM DUAL 
),
TAB1 (GRP)
AS
(
   SELECT 'AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'BBB' FROM DUAL 
)

(


SELECT 
    TAB1.GRP,
    GRPS.SUBGRP, 
    COUNT(*)
FROM TAB1
JOIN GRPS 
    ON (GRPS.GRP = TAB1.GRP)
GROUP BY TAB1.GRP,
GRPS.SUBGRP 

-- That will get me these:
-- Row# GRP SUBGRP COUNT(*)
-- 1 BBB SUB_B5 1
-- 2 AAA SUB_A2 3
-- 3 AAA SUB_A1 1
-- 4 BBB SUB_B6 2
-- From which I still have to perform a search to get me the rows with SUB_B6 AND SUB_A2


-- Expected result
-- AAA SUB_A2
-- BBB SUB_B6

)
;
```

This, of course, will not work and get me an error like "single-row subquery returns more than one row".
I dont' need to get just any row from the correlated subquery. I need to get the value from which there are more repeated from that table. In this case SUB_A2, AND SUB_B6.

Comment: Error tells you what is the problem. for `AAA` and `BBB` you have more than one row in `GPRS` CTE. Use `Top 1` in `correlated subquery` or fix the `where` clause in it

Comment: Please note the "Expected Result" part and my explanation that I need to get the data from the subquery based on the maximum number of appearance for the SUBGRP column.

Comment: Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d884d/5

Comment: Thanks a lot, but that's not exactly what I want..... I'm not looking for the SUB_A2, AND SUB_B6 values based on their descend order.... but because they are the most repeated values. I mean, I would to count them first and then check which has the more count value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Analytic Function`. Try this

```
WITH GRPS(GRP, SUBGRP)
AS
(
    SELECT 'AAA', 'SUB_A1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AAA', 'SUB_A2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AAA', 'SUB_A2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AAA', 'SUB_A2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'BBB', 'SUB_B5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'BBB', 'SUB_B6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'BBB', 'SUB_B6' FROM DUAL 
),
TAB1 (GRP)
AS
(
   SELECT 'AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'BBB' FROM DUAL 
)

(

select grp,subgrp from(
SELECT 
    TAB1.GRP,
    GRPS.SUBGRP, 
    row_number() over(partition by TAB1.GRP order by  count(1) desc) rn
FROM TAB1
JOIN GRPS 
    ON (GRPS.GRP = TAB1.GRP)
  group by TAB1.GRP,
    GRPS.SUBGRP
) a where rn=1
)
;
```

### [FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d884d/9)

Comment: Thank you!! This worked like a charm!......just curious is there any other solution that doesn't involve the Analytic Function? I remember once solved this one in SQL Server... (couldn't find the code) and it involved using a MAX, an additional subquery or a self-join I fail to remember...